# Sorting MultiIndex DataFrame format from columns to variables in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, columnsorting

I have this `DataFrame` :

```
      Age         Hgt         Wgt     
      x     y     x     y     x     y
0     26    24    160   164   95    71
1     35    37    182   163   110   68
2     57    52    175   167   89    65
```

It is a MultiIndex `DataFrame`.

I'm using `pandas` to get this **final result**:

```
      x_new    y_new    parameter     
0     26       24       Age
1     35       37       Age  
2     57       52       Age
3     160      164      Hgt           
4     182      163      Hgt             
5     175      167      Hgt              
6     95       71       Wgt     
7     110      68       Wgt     
8     89       65       Wgt
```

Basically, all the `x` columns are merged/stacked under one new column `x_new`, as well as `y` columns under `y_new` column. Always the `x` value should take the `y` value of the same raw and column.

This is what I tried to do:

**First**, I used `melt()` after I joined the column indices and became single index `'_'.join(col).strip()`
It created extra wrong rows. These wrong rows have wrong values, for example: `Age_x` and `Hgt_y` in the same row.
Remember, always, for example: `Age_x` and `Age_y` in the same row. Or, `Hgt_x` and `Hgt_y` are in the same row.

**Second**, I used `stack()`, and it gave me this result:

```
df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()
```

```
      index    Age      Hgt      Wgt
0     x        26       160      95
1     y        24       164      71  
2     x        35       182      110
3     y        37       163      68
4     x        57       175      89
5     y        52       167      65
```

I don't know what else I can do.

Is there a way to turn the MultiIndex `DataFrame` to the **final result** that I'm looking for  using simple `pandas`code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just specify to [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) `level=0` instead of the default (`level=-1`) ([`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) is used to remove the unneeded index level instead of [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) twice):

```
df.stack(level=0).droplevel(0).reset_index()

  index    x    y
0   Age   26   24
1   Hgt  160  164
2   Wgt   95   71
3   Age   35   37
4   Hgt  182  163
5   Wgt  110   68
6   Age   57   52
7   Hgt  175  167
8   Wgt   89   65
```

Add [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to order lexicographically before [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df.stack(level=0).droplevel(0).sort_index().reset_index()

  index    x    y
0   Age   26   24
1   Age   35   37
2   Age   57   52
3   Hgt  160  164
4   Hgt  182  163
5   Hgt  175  167
6   Wgt   95   71
7   Wgt  110   68
8   Wgt   89   65
```

We can further clean the output by [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`add_suffix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) to add change the index name and add the '_new' suffix to the 'x' and 'y' columns:

```
(df.stack(level=0) 
   .droplevel(0)
   .sort_index() 
   .add_suffix('_new')
   .rename_axis(index='parameter') 
   .reset_index()
)

  parameter  x_new  y_new
0       Age     26     24
1       Age     35     37
2       Age     57     52
3       Hgt    160    164
4       Hgt    182    163
5       Hgt    175    167
6       Wgt     95     71
7       Wgt    110     68
8       Wgt     89     65
```

Another round about way, using stack/unstack, since it implicitly sorts the levels:

```py
(df
.T
.unstack(1)
.stack(0)
.droplevel(1)
.rename_axis('parameter')
.add_suffix('_new')
.reset_index()
)
```

---

Setup used:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    ('Age', 'x'): [26, 35, 57], ('Age', 'y'): [24, 37, 52],
    ('Hgt', 'x'): [160, 182, 175], ('Hgt', 'y'): [164, 163, 167],
    ('Wgt', 'x'): [95, 110, 89], ('Wgt', 'y'): [71, 68, 65]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is a list comprehension, followed by a concatenation (speed-wise, I'd expect @HenryEcker's solution to be more performant, you never know till you test it, and you only test if you are keen on performance):

```py
pd.concat([df[key].add_suffix('_new')
                  .assign(parameter=key) 
           for key in df.columns.levels[0]], 
          ignore_index=True,
          sort = False,
          copy = False)

   x_new  y_new parameter
0     26     24       Age
1     35     37       Age
2     57     52       Age
3    160    164       Hgt
4    182    163       Hgt
5    175    167       Hgt
6     95     71       Wgt
7    110     68       Wgt
8     89     65       Wgt
```